# How To Measure Inches On Computer Screen?

Tags: images, paint-shop-pro

I would like to see how 3.5-inches differ from 3.7 and 4.3-inches. Is there a way i can do this on computer screen? In a Paint Shop maybe? I just want to draw rectangle according to size of inches i am interested in.

Comment: Photoshop has this tool available. Not sure about Paint Shop.

Comment: So far as I know (which isn't far) Windows knows how many pixels can be displayed on the screen but does not know the size of each pixel and so does not know the real number of pixels per inch (which can differ vertically and horizontally). Windows usually assumes 96 dpi or 120 dpi but I don't think all monitors have that many pixels per inch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will depend on the particular application you use but Adobe PhotoShop and Adobe Illustrator (and presumably Gimp) let you define your screen resolution (in pixels/inch or similar) and have an "Actual size" magnify mode.

If you mainly want to see the **relative** differences and don't need perfectly accurate scale, just plot the various lengths in a spreadsheet as a bar or column chart and resize the chart to approximate the real dimensions.

Answer (score 1):

I would use OpenOffice or LibreOffice Draw, where you can fully define size of all elements and you can easily draw there rectangles and many other geometric shapes and in vector format. :-)